Optimization fails to converge on known parameters for zero-inflated beta binomial distribution
I am trying to fit to simulated zero-inflated beta binomial data using the distributions provided by VGAM in R.
When using optim on a likelihood function I wrote, the optimization doesn't converge on the parameters I used to simulate the data. The values converged on also change depending on the initial values I input. Example:
library(VGAM)

# Simulate data
num_obs <- 1e5; num_visits <- 20; alpha <- 0.8; beta <- 0.8; psi_0 <- 0.1
sim_zoibb <- rzoibetabinom.ab(
  n = num_obs, size = num_visits, shape1 = alpha, shape2 = beta, pstr0 = psi_0)
hist(sim_zoibb, breaks = -0.5 : (num_visits + 0.5))

# Likelihood function
nll <- function(params, num_visits, data) {
  alpha <- params[1]; beta <- params[2]; psi_0 <- params[3]
  return(-1 * sum(dzoibetabinom.ab(
    x = data, size=num_visits, shape1=alpha, shape2=beta, pstr0=psi_0, log = TRUE)))
}

# Attempt maximum likelihood optimization
out <- optim(
  par = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5), fn=nll,
  num_visits=num_visits, data=sim_zoibb,
  control=list(maxit=1e6))

Optim appears to converge quickly (e.g. out$counts[1] = 150-350). At inits of c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5) it produces the parameter estimates 0.62, 0.77, 7.38e-09. When I use inits equal to the parameters I used to simulate the data, c(0.8, 0.8, 0.1), it estimates 0.71, 0.94, 5.82e-09. It seems to always estimate pstr0 (the probability of a structural zero/zero-inflation) very low/near 0.
I have tried using different optimization methods: BFGS and CG produce the error non-finite finite-difference value, L-BFGS-B produces the error L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'. SANN works, but it doesn't converge quickly, and the more iterations I let it run for, the lower it estimates pstr0 (e.g. 0.022 at 10 iterations, 0.0012 at 100 iterations, 0.00085 at 1000 iterations).
I have also attempted to use VGAM itself to fit to the data but I can't seem to find the correct zero-inflated beta binomial distribution to use. When I attempt to use a distribution without zero-inflation, I get the following error:
> vgam(sim_zoibb ~ 1, family=betabinomialff(ishape1 = 0.5, ishape2=0.5))
Error in eval(binomialff()@initialize) : 
  response values 'y' must be 0 or 1

I'm not sure what is going wrong - is there a bug in the likelihood function I wrote? Am I somehow wholly misunderstanding the optimization process?
